# Float/String values are incorrectly converted to Integers when deserializing to DataTable

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I'm posting this follow object to asp.net web server through ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/home.aspx",
   contentType:'application/json',
   data:JSON.stringify({d1:42.00,d2:3.14,d3:'17'})
});
```

When JSON.Net deserialize the object

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(stringfied);
```

d2 and d3 as seen as int, the result is:
d1 = 42, d2 = 3, d3 = 17

the problem is exactly like this post:
http://digitalbush.com/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc3-json-decimal-binding-woes/

I couldn't use this article to work around this issue because I'm using web forms.

Any way out?

**UPDATE**

Actualy the string above is wrong, this one reflects the problem, I just reproduced on Linqpad:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>("[{\"Price\":3},{\"Price\":3.33}]").Dump();
```

The result of datatable is: 3 and 3 not 3 and 3.33

If I use `DeserializeObject` method, it works properly but I need to use Datatable because I have an generic function on the app to convert Datatable to MSExcel.

Comment: What are the results if deserializing into a non-DataTable? Also, shouldn't there be an array of objects when used as a DataTable? Perhaps that is throwing things off ..

Comment: Could it be a regional settings issue? JSON Formatter fails to deserialize double and decimal due to Regional Options in Beta : http://forums.asp.net/t/1780713.aspx/1

Comment: It seems the blog post also contains an answer, that is to register a special `DecimalModelBinder`, at least to get `d2=3.14` instead of `3`. Still `d1` is an integer, but then this makes sense to me.

Comment: @pst Non-datatable works properly but I to deserialize into datatable, see the updated question please.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't think it's a regional issue, if I change the order of string to [{\"Price\":3.33},{\"Price\":3}] there is no issue.

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar yes, the blog contains the answer but it's to MVC not webforms

Answer (score 1):

With such simple data, why not use a `Generic.Dictionary`?

```
string json = "{d1:42.00, d2:3.14, d3:\"17\"}";

Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> jsonObject = (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(json);

decimal d1 = jsonObject["d1"];
decimal d2 = jsonObject["d2"];
string d3 = jsonObject["d3"];
```

Comment: My point is to workaround using DataTable method because the app has an generic function to export DataTable to MSExcel. Tks

Comment: @Alexandre If it works with serialization a non-DataTable (as per above), I would do that and then *manually* turn it into a DataTable. I suspect that the issue relates to trying to unify the values. It's not very hard to write such a function, and it should get you working on more important things :D

Comment: This is not actually an answer to above question, Its like, "Q : I am facing hurdle in my way" and answer comes "A : Leave it, take another way"

Comment: @AniketBhansali Yes, good point. I hate answers like this. I'll leave it up since there are no others at this time.